# Why my logic app if condition not working as expected

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Hello I try to schedule a logic app to work only between 15-31 every month and I created an array
[1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucGWh.png)
Then I initialize 2 variables (one in which I will store the current day and one that will help me to iterate trough the list at 1.
[2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebuVg.png)
Then I create an for each that goes trough the array with the dates and the dates (value_of_day and utcnow) will be the same
[3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfxfm.png)
But the condition evaluate as false even if they have the same value
[4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV3D2.png)

Any ideas why if fails (the vcondition is like int(variables('value_of_day')) is equal to int(variables('utcnow'))
Thanks for help :)

I tried with different types of conversion like comparing string with string and float with float and is does not work. I am out of ideas

Comment: Solved the issue with the help of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138487/azure-logic-app-condition-does-not-work-in-loop-if-based-on-changing-values?rq=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Logic App Condition does not work in loop if based on changing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138487/azure-logic-app-condition-does-not-work-in-loop-if-based-on-changing-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not suggested to change values of **"Set Variables"** in Loops as per Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-variable-store-values#set-variable) as it gives unexpected result.

Snippet from document:
[image]

I have reproduced in My environment. I was also getting same error.
[image]

Reason of the error was because value **"Value of the day"** was fixed.

I have used **Compose** to get the values of **"Value of the day"** But in **Set Variable** connecter values are changing but as you can see below in **"Compose"** value of **"Value of the day"** is fixed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

To get the expected result use **"current item"** instead of **Value of day**.

int(items('For_each')) is equal to int(variables('utcnow'))

As you can see below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**code view :**

```
   {
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose_3": {
                        "inputs": "@variables('Value of day')",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_variable_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Compose": {
                                "inputs": "@items('For_each')",
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "Compose"
                            }
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {
                                "Compose_2": {
                                    "inputs": "@items('For_each')",
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "Compose"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@int(items('For_each'))",
                                        "@int(variables('utcnow'))"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose_3": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    },
                    "Set_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Value of day",
                            "value": "@{items('For_each')}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Set_variable_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "utcnow",
                            "value": "@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd')}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Set_Period')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Period_of_time": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Set_Period",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                15,
                                16,
                                17,
                                18,
                                19,
                                20,
                                21,
                                22,
                                23,
                                24,
                                25,
                                26,
                                27,
                                28,
                                29,
                                30,
                                31
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Value of day",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Period_of_time": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "utcnow",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```